# How to verify old password first before update using shopify API

Tags: shopify

```
PUT https://key:pass@yourshop.myshopify.com/admin/customers/207119551.json
'{
  "customer": {
    "id": 207119551,
    "password": "sherbetlemon",
     "password_confirmation": "sherbetlemon"
  }
}'
```

I want to verify user's old password then sending this request for update password using Shopify API.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to generate an Access token: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/guides/updating-customers#creating-an-access-token in order to check if the credentials are correct. I haven't used this, so I can't grantee if it really works.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be doing this. Instead you probably want to change the customer account status from active to pending and resend them the request to setup their own password. Using the API to set customer passwords is borderline ridiculous and lacks clarity and security. What are going to do next, send them their new password in cleartext too to let them know how to login?

Comment: The OP could have been more clear, but I'm sure they _are_ using this flow to allow a user to change their own password. This is standard practice. If the user wants to change their password, they will need to verify that they know the old password. If so, only then will we change the password.

Comment: Customers deal with their password without intervention from API calls. If you understand how Shopify works, this is not an issue.

Comment: Using the API is a matter of preference. Why would it be "ridiculous" to use it? If you were building a site from scratch,  then you'd take the precautions to add this feature and make it secure. Why would it be a big deal to create a custom user experience outside of Shopify using an API call they created for that exact reason? Personally, my clients' sites are usually custom made. I prefer it that way because I have control. Is that so wrong?

Comment: There is NO API for dealing with customers and passwords. You can deal with customers, and you can indeed set them up so that Shopify will send them a prompt to set their own passwords, but this original post of wanting to access the passwords and do some verification all reeks doing it wrong. I am not against doing your own things, but when you play the Shopify game, you don't get to make the rules, and you don't get to mess with passwords except in the grossest of gross senses.

Comment: Maybe we are speaking of two different things. For the Storefront API, you can easily update the password by using the `customerUpdate` call. https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/customers/customerupdate

Comment: No question, but notice that mutation sets a password. How are you going to get it from the customer in the first place and know that the update is from them and not just anyone? If they are logged in, and they want to change their password, that is already built into Shopify... so why try and replicate that?